# How can I create an inherited django model instance from an existing base model instance?

Tags: django, django-models, django-inheritance

I have two django models [like these](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance):

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)

class Restaurant(Place):
    serves_hot_dogs = models.BooleanField()
    serves_pizza = models.BooleanField()
```

I had previously created a `Place` instance, like this:

```
sixth_ave_street_vendor = Place(name='Bobby Hotdogs', address='6th Ave')
sixth_ave_street_vendor.save()
```

Now bobby has upgraded his street vendor to a restaurant. How can I do that in my code?!
Why this code doesn't work:

```
sixth_ave_restaurant = Restaurant(place=sixth_ave_street_vendor,
                                  serves_hot_dogs=True,
                                  serves_pizza=True)
sixth_ave_restaurant.save()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my workaround:

```
sixth_ave_restaurant = Restaurant(place_ptr=sixth_ave_street_vendor,
                                  serves_hot_dogs=True,
                                  serves_pizza=True)
sixth_ave_restaurant.save_base(raw=True)
```

And if you want to do something else with `sixth_ave_restaurant`, you should get it again, because its `id` is not assigned yet, as it gets assigned after normal `save()`:

```
sixth_ave_restaurant = Restaurant.objects.get(id=sixth_ave_street_vendor.id)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `place_ptr` instead of `place`.

```
restaurant = Restaurant.objects.create(place_ptr=sixth_ave_street_vendor,
                                       serves_hot_dogs=True, serves_pizza=True)
```

Comment: I Set both `place_ptr` and `place_ptr_id`, but django still tries to insert a new Place :(

Comment: @RezaMohammadi that might be because `sixth_ave_street_vendor` is not yet saved, and looking into your code you haven't called the save method `sixth_ave_street_vendor.save()`

Comment: Here is another way: Create a model that called `BasePlace`, and extend the other models with that model.